# Having trouble with require path module in node.js

Tags: node.js, module, require

I am having a problem with the variable being the wrong color, which means that it does not work. Does someone know how to fix this.

[image]

Here you can see that all the other variables are blue, and that the path variable is red. I have tried using node:path, and import path.

Comment: is there an error here? if you are wanting the [nodejs standard path api](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path) i dont see anything wrong with your import

Comment: I think I just used it wrong. I just found out how. Nonetheless, thanks for answering :)